# Return max row number on every row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have part of a query here:

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ddr.number ORDER BY ddr.date) row_number,

To return the row number on each row as below

[image: | date | ddr_number | number | | |------------|----------------------------------|-----------|---| | 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 1 | | 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 2 | | 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 3 | | 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 4 | | 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |]

How could I adjust the query to return the following:

| date | ddr_number | number | Row Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |
| 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |
| 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |
| 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |
| 05/09/2022 | HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9 | 757824084 | 5 |

I want to return the max row number on every row, how can I do this without selecting max from a subquery etc, is there a way to do this by simply adjusting the window function?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want `COUNT(1) OVER.. `

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Just change `ROW_NUMBER()` to `COUNT(1)` and remove the `ORDER BY ddr.date`. It does the same as a regular count, but windowed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you just need to count number of rows per 'number'. If Yes, consider the following approach:

```
WITH ddr AS (
    SELECT '05/09/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824084' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/09/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824084' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/09/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824084' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/09/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824084' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/09/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824084' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/10/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824085' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/10/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824085' AS number UNION ALL
    SELECT '05/10/2022' AS date, 'HMCJCKIB5T6EF63RGLH1R60N2400QBV9' AS ddr_number, '757824085' AS number
)
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ddr.number ORDER BY ddr.date) AS row_number,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ddr.number) AS number_of_rows_per_number
FROM
    ddr
```

Here is the output:

[Counting number of rows per partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv6jg.png)